# How to make footer align to center in nested component scenario in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I currently have a footer that is supposed to be in the `center` but it appears to be on the left in my React app.

**CSS Styling**

```
.Footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I tried `text-align: center` and `justify-content: center` but that does not seem to work.

I created a working example using [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chilupa/pen/BaBzzeq). Could anyone please review and let me know what I was doing wrong.

Comment: try `left:0:right:0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width: 100%;` should get you the behavior you're looking for. `position: fixed` takes it outside of the flow of the DOM so the default behavior of a block element expanding to match its parent isn't evident due to it no longer having a parent.